# Increase volume on mac using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I found the command, but can I do it in AppleScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can: use `set volume output volume N`, where *`N`* is an integer from `0` to `100`.  Since there are 16 squares in the volume interface, and 100/16 = 6.25, there's no direct map from squares to this number, but you'll be fine if you think about it as a percentage.  There's also the ability to set the input volume with `set volume input volume N`, and the alert volume with `set volume alert volume N`; `set volume output muted BOOL` mutes the output if *`BOOL`* is `true`, and unmutes it if it's `false`.  (Alternatively, `set volume ... with output muted` or `set volume ... without output muted`.)  You can stack these if you want to set multiple things at once.  As [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220582/increase-volume-on-mac-using-applescript/4220624#4220624) says, there's also `set volume R`, which (according to my docs) takes a real number between 0 and 7; however, this is *deprecated*, and has a strange range; I'd just use `set volume output volume` instead.  If you want to query the current volume, you can run `get volume settings`, which returns a record of the form `{output volume:82, input volume:46, alert volume:100, output muted:false}`.