# Changing Mac volume to a variable in terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sh

I'm trying to create a shell script in which I change the volume to max, use the `Say` command and then change the volume back. So far I'm able to save the old volume as a variable, change the volume to maximum and use the say command. The only trouble I'm having is changing the volume to the variable value.

What I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

VOL=$(osascript -e 'output volume of (get volume settings)')
osascript -e 'set Volume 100'
say Hello 
osascript -e "set Volume $VOL"
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `set Volume x` uses a volume scale of 0 to 7, while `output volume of (get volume settings)` uses a scale of 0 to 100. You could multiply by 0.07, but there's an easier solution, pointed out by [Antal Spector-Zabusky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220582/increase-volume-on-mac-using-applescript/4220671#4220671): use `set volume output volume n`, which uses the 0-100 scale.

```
vol=$(osascript -e 'output volume of (get volume settings)')
osascript -e "set volume output volume 100"
#say "Hello"
osascript -e "set volume output volume $vol"
```